# Is it possible to define a nested anonymous namespace's member name outside?

Tags: c++, namespaces

If I have an anonymous namespace that is nested in another namespace and the former has a declaration for a function. So how can I define that function outside the namespaces?

```
namespace A{
    namespace{
        void foo();
    }
}

void A::foo(){} // error: 'void A::f()' should have been declared inside 'A'
```

- So is it possible to define `foo()` outside (here in the global namespace)?

Answer (score 2):

Make the anonymous namespace into an inline one as well.

```
namespace A {
    inline namespace {
        void foo();
    }
}
```

It will spill `foo` into `A` proper for most intents and purposes, as though it was decalred there directly. But the static linkage brought about by the unnamed namespace is kept.

Just like with direct members of `A`, your definition will be valid.